# Wrap table rows without breaking HTML validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and I want to wrap **table rows** , but the problem is I don't know **with what** to wrap those those guys up... If I use `<div>`,`<span>`,`<tr>`,`<td>`...they all break my validation. 
So with what can I wrap my table-rows ***without breaking validation***?

This is how I want it to look only problem is that my HTML is not valid.

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RbpKz/)**

I am generating my wrappers using following Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('tr:first').nextUntil('.section2').andSelf().addClass('section1');
$('tr:nth-child(3)').removeClass('section1').addClass('section2');
$('.section2').nextUntil('.section3').removeClass('section1').addClass('section2');

//Lets wrap those two sections inside divs ...
//This will obviously break my validation:(    
$('tr.section1').wrapAll('<div class="section_box1"></div>');
$('tr.section2').wrapAll('<div class="section_box2"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Why wrap them in anything? Could you just give each row a specific class? Also why tables in the first place?

Comment: Can't do that because I will use slideUp/slideDown effect...

Comment: There are only 4 elements that can contain a table row: `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`, and `table`. Of those, only one `thead` and `tfoot` can exist within a single table, therefore `tbody` is the only option you have as far as wrapping `tr` elements. You should instead just slideDown/slideUp the individual rows, **or consider not animating table rows because it's going to be buggy**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @KevinB writes in a comment, a `tbody` element is really the only way to group table rows in a wrapper element. In static markup, this could be:

```
<table class="form-table">

    <tbody class="bg">
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">Hide Menu Background:</th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="value1" name="name1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">
                Menu Background:
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name=""/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    

    <tbody class="other">
        <tr  valign="top">
            <th  scope="row">Hide Sidebar:</th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="value2" name="name2"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">Hide Site Title:</th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="value3" name="name3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `class` attributes on `tbody` elements are really not needed, but they can be used to make styling a little easier.

Alternatively, you might decide that the two parts are not really logically parts of the same table, and use two separate `table` elements. This is really the only way if you want column 2 to start at different positions.

Comment: You both guys are right!! Right now I am experimenting with animations and it looks like it will work like a charm. Vote up+

Comment: Work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I would first start by just removing the table to begin with.  It is really only best practice to use a table when actual 'tabular data' is being shown.

```
<h3 class="title">General Settings:</h3>
<div class="section_box1">
    Hide Menu Background: <input type="checkbox" value="value1" name="name1"/><br />
    Menu Background: <input type="file" name=""/>
</div>
<div class="section_box2">
    Hide Sidebar: <input type="checkbox" value="value2" name="name2"/><br />
    Hide Site Title: <input type="checkbox" value="value3" name="name3" />
</div>
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RbpKz/1/).

This way you can more freely add classes / wrappers as needed and still be HTML compliant.

Comment: The table will be dynamically generated by Wordpress settings API so unfortunately I can't do anything about it...

Comment: @DejoDekic Technically you could use javascript to transform the table into divs if you had to, though that's very *hack'n slash*

Comment: Sounds like a hot mess all together then

Comment: Whether this is tabular data is a matter of opinion, and the opinion that a table should not be used does not help to format the table.

Comment: Thanks Jukka, you are correct this is not a matter of opinion. It's FACT this is NOT tabular data. http://goo.gl/GyeLZ